# how to add a do-while statement to this?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I need to make it do it repeatedly asks the user for a number between 1 and 10, but it terminates when any number is entered.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

       int n;

       n = Integer.parseInt(
               JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                       "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));

       while (n < 1 && n > 10) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is not between 1 and 10");
               n = Integer.parseInt(
                       JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                               "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));
       }

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good!\nClick OK to exit");
       System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can this ever be true? `(n < 1 && n > 10)`? Can a number ever be less than 1 and greater than 10 at the same time?

Comment: use (n < 1 || n > 10) instead of (n < 1 && n > 10)

Comment: @elsadek at n=5; ur condition evaluates to `false||false` = `false` and hence `while()` loop exits and reaches to `System.exit(0);` which is unwanted(read ques again). `System.exit(0);` shud be called when 1<n<10.

Comment: @KNU indeed XOR will make sense :(n < 1 ^ n > 10)

Comment: @user3247712 You need to accept one of answer if it answers your question. plz do accept any one below to motivate the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `AND` to `OR`:

```
while (n < 1 || n > 10) { ... }
```

... and consider the possibility of turning this into `do-while` loop, as you have to show that prompt at least once.

```
int n;
do {
   n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
       "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));
   if (n >= 1 && n <= 10) {
     break;
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is not between 1 and 10");
} while (true);

// do something useful with n, will you? )
```

Comment: I would +1 again, but I can't :) This is the neatest way of handling incorrect user input I have seen so far. :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Thanks. ) In fact, `do{ input = prompt(); if (valid(input)) break; alert(); } while(true);` is a common idiom when dealing with user input, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop indefinitely, then I suggest using `while(true)` and then a break statement (you don't need a break in this case since you call `System.exit(0)`)--that is often times easier then trying to code the proper `while` or `do while` loop.

```
while(true){
    final int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));
    if(n >= 1 && n <= 10){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good!\nClick OK to exit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // else continue loop
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is not between 1 and 10");
}
```

or this could have been:

```
while(true){
    final int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));
    if(n >= 1 && n <= 10)
        break;
    // else continue loop
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is not between 1 and 10");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good!\nClick OK to exit");
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your program lacks proper structure and logical implementation.

Since you want to exit the user only when entered number is between 1 and 10 the correct logic should be

```
boolean userWantsToExit = false;
while (!userWantsToExit) {
   //hey user set n ;
   int n = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                   "Enter a number between 1 and 10"));
   if(n >= 1 && n <= 10){
     //reached here , means user want's to exit
     userWantsToExit = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use (n < 1 ^ n > 10) instead of (n < 1 && n > 10) 
..and keep your code as it is!

Comment: there is an easier and more readable alternative `(n>1 || n<10)` ALSO `x XOR y = (~x)&y OR x(~y)` which requires more computation.

Comment: you mean: !(n>1 || n<10) , for the code to remain intact, isn't it?